# pthread_once and mutex lock

Tags: c, multithreading

I have the following code executed by multiple threads.

```
alloc_global_ctx()
{
  if (global ctx is not allocated) {
    global ctx = calloc(1, sizeof(global ctx));
  }
  return global ctx;
}

once_routine()
{
   ….
   alloc_global_ctx()
   ….
}

init_routine()
{
    Take init_mutex;
    Call pthread_once(once_variable, once_routine);
    alloc_global_ctx();
    ….
    Release init_mutex;
}
```

When `init_routine` is executed by my program ( 2 threads calling `init_routine`), I expected that the global `ctx` will be allocated by the thread which executes `once_routine`.  However, from the debug logs, I found that most of the times, thread running `once_routine` and thread allocating global variable are different.  Is this expected? When a thread is executing `pthread_once`, does it release the `init_mutex`?

Comment: You need to post a complete example. Your code cannot be compiled and run, so we cannot see what you see.

Comment: pthread_once has no knowledge of your init_mutex, so something else is going on - which cannot be read from the pseudo code posted here. However since you already protect the region with a mutex, there would be no need for a pthread_once call, or you could get rid of the mutex and only rely on pthread_once.

Comment: How is "once_variable" defined?